# How do you enable ASICBOOST on an s9

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

How do you enable ASICBOOST on an Antminer s9?

Comment: It's a secret that nobody is willing to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Bitmain](https://blog.bitmain.com/en/new-firmware-activate-overt-asicboost-bm1387-antminer-models/) and [Braiins](https://twitter.com/braiins_systems/status/1055153228772503553) have now released S9 firmware that enables overt AsicBoost.